# What should I define type for an Object when we pass as an argument to function in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am not getting what should we define the type for an Object whenever we pass Object as argument to function in the React Typescript. I did some changes to the function parameter by assigning the type "any" but I just wanted to avoid to give type as "any" while passing object as parameter to function. Can you please look into below code and please tell what should be the proper type ?

```
export interface DataObj {
  label: string,
  image: string,
  body: string, 
}

interface PropsFunction {
  toggleShow: (item: object) => void;
  data: DataObj;
  show: boolean;
  setShow: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const Test = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState<DataObj>({
    label: "",
    image: "",
    body: " 
  }); 

// need to know type here for data
  const toggleShow = (data: any) => {
    setShow(!show);
    setData(data);
  };
}
```

Comment: const toggleShow = (data: DataObj) => {
    setShow(!show);
    setData(data);
  };
Does this not work

Comment: Nope getting this issue void' is not assignable to type '(item: object) => void'.

Comment: interface PropsFunction {
  toggleShow: (item: DataObj) => void;
  data: DataObj;
  show: boolean;
  setShow: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}
can you change the interface

Answer (score 0):

you can use `type` for such case. Lets assume you have object as below:

```
let obj = {
  fruit: "mango",
  available: true,
  stock: 10
}

type fruitType = {
  fruit: string,
  available: boolean,
  stock: number
}

interface market {
  fruit: fruitType
}
```

Also you can use type of method also as below:

```
const method = (data: fruitType): void => {
  // code block
  return;
}
```

Comment: Getting this issue void' is not assignable to type '(item: object) => void'.

Comment: you may forget to return value since (item: object) => void want your method to have return value: hope this blog may help you : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-argument-type-void-not-assignable-parameter-type

Comment: like this: const method = (data: fruitType) : void => { // some code \n return; };